# Linear Map that maps the disk of radius 2 to the lower half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Is their a general procedure to find a linear transformation that maps $\Delta(n)$, the disc of radius $n\in\mathbb{N}$, to the lower half plane? For example, how can I find linear map that maps $\Delta(2)$ to the lower half plane of $\mathbb{C}$? I am aware that I somehow have to use the cross ratio and define the map at three points but still don't understand how one achieves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, people do use the cross-ratio, but I just do it by guess and by golly. Here’s my method:

I’m going to try to send the topmost point $ni$ of the boundary of the disk to the origin, and the two real points $-n$ and $n$ on the boundary to $-1$ and $1$, respectively. I’m going to hope that $-ni$ goes to $\infty$, too.

Just dealing with $ni\mapsto0$ gives me
\begin{equation}z\mapsto\frac{z-ni}{Cz+D}\,,\end{equation}and I want to choose $C$ and $D$ so that the two real points go to $\pm1$.
\begin{matrix}
\text{For }-1:&\frac{-n-ni}{-nC+D}&=-1&\text{so}&nC-D=&-n-ni\\
\text{For }1:&\frac{n-ni}{nC+D}&=1&\text{so}&nC+D=&n-ni
\end{matrix}
Thus we get $C=-i$, and $D=n$. Our fractional-linear map should be
\begin{equation}z\mapsto\frac{z-ni}{-iz+n}\,,\end{equation}
in which the denominator does indeed become zero under $z=-in$. Just to check, let’s see where the origin goes: $0\mapsto-ni/n=-i$, which indeed is in the lower half-plane. That’s it!

Comment: Thank you for you nicely explained answer!

Comment: I learned this way back in the days when stones were soft, in a wonderful course taught by Ahlfors. It was my first year of grad school, and at first I thought all this fiddling with fractional-linear functions was some kind of baby-talk. But it gave me a great deal of geometric understanding.